# PHP can't upload Document if the file size is more than 100mb

Tags: php, html, mysql

> =============================================
>
> I can only upload if the size of file is KB but in MB it can't. How
>   can i do this? I am new in PHP.
>
> This is my code
>
> < ?php
>
> if(isset($_POST['upload'])&&$_FILES['userfile']['size']>0)
>       {
>
> ```
>     $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
>     $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
>
>     $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
>     $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
>     $fileType=(get_magic_quotes_gpc()==0 ? mysql_real_escape_string(
>     $_FILES['userfile']['type']) : mysql_real_escape_string(
>     stripslashes ($_FILES['userfile'])));
>     $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
>     $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
>     $content = addslashes($content);
>     $description = $_POST['description'];
>     fclose($fp);
>     if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
>     {
>         $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
>     }
>     $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'intelligence') or die(mysql_error());
>     $db = mysql_select_db('db_profile', $con);
>     if($db){
>     $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_docs (name, size, type, content, description) ".
>     "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content', '$description')";
>     mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 
>     mysql_close();
>     header("location: ../main.php");        }
>     else { 
>      header('location:../View/View.php');   
>     }
> }  ?>
> ```
>
> Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on your `PHP.INI` file configuration. Look for the entrance `upload_max_filesize` and put there the size limit you want. And then restart your server.

It should look something like this:

```
 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 ; File Uploads ;
 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

 ; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
 ; http://php.net/file-uploads
 file_uploads = On

 ; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
 ; specified).
 ; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
 upload_tmp_dir = "C:\Dev\xampp\tmp"

 ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
 ; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
 upload_max_filesize = 2M   <<<<<<----------------- THIS IS THE VALUE YOU MUST CHANGE

 ; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
 max_file_uploads = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP.ini, set these variables to mentioned values:

```
memory_limit = 96M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```